# Building full gcc under MinGw

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm trying to build gcc 4.7.2 under MinGw with cc,c++,fortran,objc and java.
When it reaches to the compiling libgcc at final linking level it gives an error.

> cannot find dllcrt2.o

Followed by

> cannot find -lmingwthrd,-lmingw32,-lmingwex,-lmoldname,-lmsvcrt,-ladvapi,-lshell32,-luser32,-lkernal32

I think this is because ld.exe couldn't locate /mingw/lib dir.Is there any solution to fix this?I tried googling but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the MinGw compilers they ship that you are trying to build your own set?

Configuring/building GCC is a complex task (even more so in such a hostile environment), a small slip up can lead to results like the ones you see. Recheck each step.

Grab a copy of the source for MinGw and study how they do it, check their documentation.

Comment: Besides, I don't think all the languages are supported on windows (java in particular).

Comment: I don't need to build every thing.I just need gcj.But since I'm building I desided to try cc,c++ and fortran too.Yes I can use mingw but minge dropped gcj at gcc 3 or something...

Comment: In fact dllcrt2.o is in mingw core installation and it's located in /mingw/lib .Ld just can't find it.